# Open a particular instance in `where` statement in Agda

Tags: agda

When I write a lot of agda code I always end up having this cumbersome pattern in my code. Suppose I have this `record` type defining a mathematical structure:

```
record A (T : Set) : Set where
    m1 = -- ...
    m2 = -- ...
    m3 = -- ...
    field
        f1 : -- ...
        f2 : -- ...
        f3 : -- ...
```

then I prove a property of this structure `A`:

```
theorem : ∀ {S} -> A S -> -- ...
theorem a = -- ...
    where
        m1 = A.m1 a
        m2 = A.m2 a
        f1 = A.f1 a
        f2 = A.f2 a
        -- ...
```

This is very annoying. I could `open A` but then I just have `m1`, `m2` that maps `a` to the object I want. I want something like `open a` so that `m1` refers directly to `(A.m1 a)`. I couldn't find anything on this matter in Agda documentation. Is there such syntactic sugar? This problem is responsible of great majority (maybe >60% of my code). In every single theorem I open up the whole structure... What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Records are also modules, so `... where open A a` will work

Comment: [Relevant part of the manual](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/record-types.html#record-modules)

Comment: Uhh... gotcha. I don't know how I missed that! Thank you very much! Could one of you please make an answer so that I can accept it?